# Need some explanation about how the hex to decimal algorithm works

Tags: java, algorithm, hex, decimal

The algorithm below converts hex to decimal, but I've confused, how this solution works?

```
public static int hex2decimal(String s) {
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int d = digits.indexOf(c);
        val = 16*val + d;
    }
    return val;
}
```

[source](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Hex2Decimal.java.html)

I had known only one approach to do that before I found out this one.
I mean, everyone knows:
**`X*16^Y`** where **`X`** is the number you want to convert and **`Y`** is the position for the number (begging from the end to the start).

So, if you want to convert *`DA145`* to decimal would be...

```
*(5 * 16^0) + (4 * 16^1) + (1 * 16^2) + (10 * 16^3) + (13 * 16^4)*
```

Comment: It is actually faster (negligibly usually, unless you are running this code repeatedly) to use `|` and `<< 4` instead of `+` and `* 16`, since you are basically just editing nibbles. Also, I think there exists a method in the `java.lang.Integer` class that does that?

Comment: @Pemap modder thanks and I'm sure it exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This algorithm uses the fact that we can calculate 16^Y by repeatedly multiply together 16's and also that we can factor out common multiplications by 16. From your example you would instead end at:

```
13*16 + 10)*16 + 1)*16 + 4)*16 + 5
```

I've omitted the leading parentheses, as you see it happens to be that 13 is in effect multiplied with 16 four times.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm does pretty much the same as you would do it. It takes a String and compares every single char with the given value. This value is evaluated by digits, at which position it stands (e.g. A is in the 10th position, since we start counting with 0). This allows to easily change it e.g. to a 17 digit system instead of hexadezimal.

Edit: About the powers of 16, look at @skykings answer.